Multiple redirects using React router dom
I'm using React Router to redirect to a login page when user is not logged in, like this:
return (
    <main className="App  relative">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<AuthLayout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
        </Route>

        <Route path='/*' element={<PrivateRoute/>}>
          <Route path="/*" element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />           
            <Route path="timeline" element={<TimeLine />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </main>
);

this is my PrivateRoute:
const PrivateRoute = () => {    
    const [currentUser] = useAtom(currentUserAtom);
    const isAuth = (currentUser && currentUser.token);

    const prevLocation = useLocation();
    var redirectTo = `/login?redirectTo=${prevLocation.pathname}`;
    console.log(redirectTo);        
    return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to={redirectTo} />;
}

export default PrivateRoute;

The problem is that the PrivateRoute executes 3 times, with these results:
/login?redirectTo=/dashboard 
/login?redirectTo=/login
/login?redirectTo=/login

And the final redirect page is http://localhost:5173/login?redirectTo=/login instead of http://localhost:5173/login?redirectTo=/dashboard
What's wrong?
